# How to use Apache Spark in Arch?

Tags: apache-spark, archlinux

I want to resolve the error when I run `spark-shell`

I am on arch installing apache spark  from the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/apache-spark/)

When I run the command `spark-shell` I get the following error

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I also installed the `slf4j` from aur and it does not help either. how can run spark on arch

Comment: How about installing hadoop as mentionned in the [AUR comment](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/apache-spark/)?

Comment: You are right that solved it. MangoMan saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a problem regarding Java which I canno't help you with...

Did you do the correct configuration for Spark ?

> cd /etc/profile.d
>
> sudo nano apache-spark.sh

Modifiy : `SPARK_HOME=/opt/apache-spark` by `SPARK_HOME=/opt/apache-spark/bin`

Worked for me